# API return image

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to fetch a byte array from the database and return it as image like [this](https://img.dxcdn.com/productimages/sku_94630_1.jpg)

```
public IActionResult Get(string PictureCode)
{
    SqlParameter[] parameters = {new SqlParameter("@PictureCode", PictureCode) };
    var PD = db.Picture.FromSql("SIP_API_MONDIA_ItemPicture_sel @PictureCode", parameters).ToList();
    var contents = new MemoryStream(PD[0].PictureData);
    return File(contents, "image/png"); 
}
```

Edit:
1) PD is of type PictureModel

> var PD = db.Picture.FromSql("SIP_API_MONDIA_ItemPicture_sel
>   @PictureCode", parameters).ToList();

Picture Model:

```
public class PictureModel
{
    [Key]
    public byte[] PictureData { get; set; }
}
```

Error: [image]

Edit2: Stored procedure sample:

```
GO
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[SIP_API_MONDIA_ItemPicture_sel]
(
 @PictureCode int = null
)
As
Begin

 If @PictureCode is not null
 Begin
    Select t1.PictureData From T_Picture t1 Where t1.PictureCode = @PictureCode
 End

 return 0
End
```

Where PictureData is type of varbinary(max) in T_Picture

Edit3: The Middleware, where the error(see print screen) happens:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        // Add middleware before MVC
        app.Use(async (ctx, next) =>
        {
            // Capture the original response body stream
            var responseStream = ctx.Response.Body;

            // Replace it with our own, so that we can read it
            using (var bodyStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                ctx.Response.Body = bodyStream;

                //if (ctx.Request.Path.Value.Contains("customers") && !ctx.Request.QueryString.Value.Contains("?$expand"))
                //{
                //    ctx.Response.Redirect($"" + ctx.Request.Path.Value + "?$expand=FreeFields,Contact,Address");

                //}
                // Run ASP.NET MVC (ie. get the results back from your code)
                await next();

                // Put the original response body stream back
                ctx.Response.Body = responseStream;

                // Read the one that we captured
                bodyStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                var responseBody = await new StreamReader(bodyStream).ReadToEndAsync();

                // If it's ODATA & JSON & 200 (success), replace the "value" with "results"
                if (ctx.Response.ContentType.Contains("application/json") && ctx.Response.ContentType.Contains("odata") && ctx.Response.StatusCode == 200)
                {
                    responseBody = responseBody.Replace("\"value\"", "\"results\"");
                }

                // Write back the response body (whether modified or not) to the original response stream
                await ctx.Response.WriteAsync(responseBody);
            }
        });

        app.UseMvc(b =>
        {
            b.Select().Expand().Filter().OrderBy().MaxTop(100).Count();
            b.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "odata", GetEdmModel());
        });
    }
```

Comment: what does `db.Picture.FromSql` code look like? can you edit your question to show this?

Comment: Hi Alex, https://imgur.com/VL42g7P it's a byte array

Comment: can you edit your question to include the code please, not an image of the code.

Comment: @Alex How, it's a very long byte array. I'll provide a proper scrnshot in question a sec.

Comment: I'm not going to read a byte array. I want to see the CODE that creates the byte array! `db.Picture.FromSql` - there is code behind this... what does it look like. Please edit your question to include this CODE

Comment: There is no code.. it's just EF executing a SQL procedures which returns a string which I'll put in question

Comment: There is code behind `db.Picture.FromSql` - `FromSql` isn't a .net API.

Comment: Yeah. there is a Picturemodel.  DB is my DbContext, how is that relevant?

Comment: unfortunately, without seeing the code behind `db.Picture.FromSql` or your stored proc, can't help any further.

Comment: Hi @Alex, I can't share the stored prc, I can just tell you that it returns a Varbinary type. 
FromSql is just standard Entity Framework syntax. db is the DbContext class and Picture is simply:         public DbSet<PictureModel> Picture { get; set; }
which is also standard EF, so I really have no clue what you mean with "seeing the code behind db.picture.fromsql"

Comment: Can't share the stored prc? Why? How are we supposed to help you with this, if you won't share the code. MCVE is needed here - https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve - the problem could very likely be in the way your stored proc is querying the db, but we'll never know.

Comment: @Alex I provided a sample of the proc. ;)

Comment: i can't reproduce it; I would guess maybe the way the images are saved in the db is perhaps causing the problem? If you manually copy the base64 from your db, and paste it to http://freeonlinetools24.com/base64-image - then click decode, does that render your expected image?

Comment: Uhm that url expect it to be base64 while in the DB it's a byte array, I converted the byte array to to a base64 and posted the result in the website you provided and that seemed fine. I could see the image as intended. Is it possible that I can't return it because it's too big somehow? @Alex

Comment: I don't see any specific reason for that particular exception, but it's completely unecessary to wrap it in a `MemoryStream`. The byte[] *already* in-memory, so you're just doubling up the memory usage. `File` can take a byte[], so just return the data directly.

Comment: Is it possible that there are 7-bit (ASCII) bytes getting mixed in somewhere? I say this because of the ratio between the number of bytes expected vs written as shown in the exception message is roughly 7/8.

Comment: I cannot  reproduce your issue based on the existing code provided .What is the complete part of the code highlighted in the error message?  Could you share a demo that can reproduce the issue ? You could also have a look [this link](https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/issues/1289) which may be helpful .

Comment: @XueliChen I edited my question with the middleware. I think it's something there.